# 固定キーの保持方法について

Tags: android

とあるサーバに対して、作成したアプリからのみ通信を許可したいと考えています。

現在はアプリ内のソースに固定の文字列を保持して、
アプリ内で演算を行った結果の文字列を
サーバと通信時に付与してサーバ側で検証することで通信を許可していましたが

アプリは簡単にデコードでき、固定の文字列および演算方法は簡単にユーザにばれてしまうと指摘を受けました

この様なケースの場合、アプリ内でどのように固定キーを隠ぺいすればよろしいでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

古い投稿ですが、以前、同様の質問が以下でもされていました。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21465559/restrict-api-requests-to-only-my-own-mobile-app

基本的にpublicなAPIであれば、特定のアプリからのみのリクエストを受け付けることは難しいと思います。
認証機能やIP制限等である程度制限をかけるのが限界かと思います。

リンクだけでも共有出来た方が良いと思い、回答させていただきました。